# Refreshing issues between Android 4 and Android 5

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment in which there are some options like add, edit, remove. When the user completes some action I use the below code in order to refresh the fragment.

```
   Fragment fragment = new FragmentA();
   FragmentManager fragmentManager = MyApplication.getFragmentManager();
   fragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commitAllowingStateLoss();
   fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.right_panel, fragment).addToBackStack("dummy").commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

In Android 4 works fine. But in android 5 doesn't work. The user have to exit from screen and when he re-enter then the content is ok. 
Also, I have try with detach & attach, and add instead of replace, but both of them don't work.

FragmentCode

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {

    public ArrayList<String> objectIds = new ArrayList<>();
    public ArrayList<String> images = new ArrayList<>(); //urls of ParseFiles
    public ArrayList<String> locations = new ArrayList<>();
    public QueriesController queriesController = new QueriesController();
    public MyAdapter adapter;
    public RecyclerView recyclerView;

    public FragmentA() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentA, container, false);


        MyApplication.setActivityContext(getActivity());
        MyApplication.setFragmentManager(getFragmentManager());

        //set the recycler view
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        //This component positions item views inside the row and determines when it is time to recycle the views.
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);

        populateRV();


        return rootView;
    }

    /**
     * populate recycler view
     */
    public void populateRV() {

        objectIds.clear();
        images.clear();
        locations.clear();

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = queriesController.getItemsOfUser();
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Log.i("score", "Retrieved " + list.size() + " scores");
                    for (ParseObject item : list) {

                        objectIds.add(item.getObjectId());
                        images.add(item.getParseFile("image").getUrl());
                        locations.add(item.getString("location"));
                    }

                    //set the adapter for recyclerView
                    adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(),
                            objectIds, images, locations);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


                } else {
                    Log.i("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the fragment which is currently loaded but you are trying to remove a new instance of the fragment.

**Solution 1**

Replace

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

with

```
Fragment old = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.right_panel);
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(old).commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

**Solution 2**

Simply detach and attache the fragment again, but don't use a new instance. Use the one which is currently loaded.

```
Fragment currentFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.right_panel);
FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragTransaction.detach(currentFragment);
fragTransaction.attach(currentFragment);
fragTransaction.commit();
```

**Note:** Personally I would prefer second solution.

Comment: The old fragment is the fragment which I want to load.. As I said I want to refresh the fragment itself

Comment: Yes, but you need to remove the instance which is loaded not a new one.

Comment: Ok! I understand what did you said and you are right. Now I will try the solution 1. When I had tried the solution 2 I had a problem.. I was able to add/edit/remove the first time but in the second time my app was crashed.

Comment: @user4292106: If it crashed then something is wrong and according to me you shouldn't ignore it.

Comment: The solution 1 works on Android 4 but not in Android 5 (content doesn't refresh immediatly). In solution 2 I completed an add action and when I try second time to add an item I get this java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failure saving state: has cleared index: -1

Comment: Try using `commit()` rather than `commitAllowingStateLoss()`

Comment: I tried with commit() instead of commitAllowingStateLoss() but I am getting the same error..

Comment: Why can't you just add data to your adapter and call `notifyDataSetChanged`. It will refresh itself with new data

Comment: Because my data are coming from parse. When a user add an item then this item should be stored in database. So I call inside from SaveCallBack the code for the transaction of fragment

Comment: You know exactly when you need to refresh the fragment. At that moment rather than detaching and attaching the fragment again simply update the adapter and call notifyDataSetChanged.

Comment: Yes you are right. But on AddItem a new activity is open. so maybe I could call notifyDataChanged in onResume?

Comment: I tried also with onResume and it works fine in android 4.. In android 5 doesn't work. I can't understand the reason why...